# wrong input of image in tensorflow for training

Tags: python, image, image-processing, tensorflow2.0

I am writing my thesis in machine learning and am trying to build a unet to perform it. The code is as follows:

First i create the dataloader to create the datasets for input:

```
def dataloader(filepath, subset):
    # Initiliaze return arrays - input of shape = HYPERPARAMETER
    global size
    if subset=="train":
        size = 129
    elif subset=="test":
        size = 18
    input_data=np.zeros((size,1024,1024,1))
    output_data=np.zeros((size,1024,1024,1))
    # Open file and create loop
    with open(filepath+"annotation_"+subset+".txt", "r") as input_file:
        # Count to pass through the file
        count=0
        for line in input_file:
            line=line.split(" ")
            data=cv2.imread(filepath+str(line[0])+".jpg",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            input_data[count,:,:,0]=data
            # Case of benevolent
            if line[3]=="B":
                x=int(line[4])
                y=1024-int(line[5])
                radius=int(line[6])
                for i in range(1024):
                    for j in range(1024):
                        if ((radius*radius-(i-x)*(i-x)-(j-y)*(j-y))>0):
                            # Setting 80 as th value of the benevolent mask
                            output_data[count,i,j,0]=80
            # Case of malevolent
            elif line[3]=="M":
                x=int(line[4])
                y=1024-int(line[5])
                radius=int(line[6])
                for i in range(1024):
                    for j in range(1024):
                        if ((radius*radius-(i-x)*(i-x)-(j-y)*(j-y))>0):
                            # Setting 160 as th value of the benevolent mask
                            output_data[count,i,j,0]=160
            if count==0:
                print(type(data))
                print(type(input_data))
                cv2.imshow('test',data)
                cv2.waitKey(0)
                cv2.imshow('image',input_data[count,:,:,0])
                cv2.waitKey(0)
                cv2.imshow('mask',output_data[count,:,:,0])
                cv2.waitKey(0)
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()             
            count=count+1
    #input_data=K.zeros_like(input_data)
    #output_data=K.zeros_like(output_data)
    return input_data, output_data
```

and then the model and the commands to run it:

```
def unet_model(optimizer, loss_metric, metrics, sample_width, sample_height, lr=1e-3):
    inputs = Input((sample_width, sample_height, 1))
    print(inputs.shape)
    conv1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    drop1 = Dropout(0.5)(pool1)

    conv2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(drop1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
    drop2 = Dropout(0.5)(pool2)

    conv3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(drop2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
    drop3 = Dropout(0.3)(pool3)

    conv4 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(drop3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv4)
    drop4 = Dropout(0.3)(pool4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(drop4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv5)

    up6 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(256, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv5), conv4], axis=3)
    conv6 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv6)

    up7 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(128, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv6), conv3], axis=3)
    conv7 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv7)

    up8 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv7), conv2], axis=3)
    conv8 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv8)

    up9 = concatenate([Conv2DTranspose(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv8), conv1], axis=3)
    conv9 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv9)

    conv10 = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='softmax')(conv9)

    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[conv10])

    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer(lr=lr), loss=loss_metric, metrics=metrics)
    return model


#Filepath of datasets
filepath = "/home/tzikos/Downloads/train/"

# Load datasets
train_input, train_output = dataloader(filepath, "train")
test_input, test_output = dataloader(filepath, "test")
train_input = normalize(train_input)
test_input = normalize(test_input)
train_output = normalize(train_output)
test_output = normalize(test_output)
print(train_input.shape)
print(train_output.shape)
print(test_input.shape)
print(test_output.shape)

# Load model
model = unet_model(optimizer=Adam, loss_metric=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(), metrics=["accuracy"], sample_width=train_input.shape[1], sample_height=train_input.shape[2],lr=1e-3)
model.compile(optimizer="Adam", loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(), metrics=["accuracy"])
history = model.fit(x=train_input, y=train_output, batch_size=1, epochs=30)

# Save weights
model_filepath = '/home/tzikos/Desktop/thesis_DENSE-IN-UNET/unet_weights.h5'
model.save(model_filepath)

# Check results
results = model.evaluate(test_input, test_output)
print(results)
```

So the problem is the following:

When I train my model i get 0 accuracy and no change in the loss function. So I went and dived into the images.

When I imshow the data variable i get the photo as should be. However when I input it into the numpy array it is transcribed into a binary one where there is black and white and idk why.

So I think that is the problem but i cant see why that is since the data variable is allright

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what this network is supposed to do, so I will list some mistakes that in your code.

In your function you already compile the model:

```
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer(lr=lr), loss=loss_metric, metrics=metrics)
return model
```

After outside the function you do it again:

```
model.compile(optimizer="Adam", loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(), metrics=["accuracy"])
```

One issue is about metric and loss. `tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()` is a regression loss and `'accuracy'` is a classification metric.

The most obvious one:

```
conv10 = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='softmax')(conv9)
```

`Softmax` activation will be applied to your last axis. If you check your `model.summary()` your last axis consist of size 1 which means you have a single element. So you are just returning(outputting) a vector of ones everytime.

Comment: thank you very much for your feedback. I will correct any mistakes and if a problem persists that I canbot deal with i will ask again.

Comment: this however doenst change the fact that my image problem doesnt change. Can you help with that?

Comment: What does this network supposed to do? You need to re-set loss etc.

Comment: I fixed it all. The network though is supposed to do semantic segmentation to images for brain tumour

Comment: If your problem is solved please consider accepting the answer, if there are more problems let me know so I can edit the answer.

Comment: I solved te problem wit the photos. However the problem with the metrics persists. The accuracy should be very high not close to 0. Do you know as to why that may be ?

Comment: Which loss function do you use? Did you change anything in the code?

Comment: I changed the dtype of the np.zeros to uint8 and fixed the issue with the photos and deleted the normalize function applications.The metrics I kept the same because i cant find which other metrtics to use. The accuracy however should be really high from projects that I saw.

Comment: In your last Conv layer use `sigmoid` instead of `softmax` and as a loss try to use `binary_crossentropy`. Using accuracy with MSE is not a valid option.

Comment: I have done as u requested but the problem persists. I get loss that diminishes but accuracy is stuck at zero.